# Can't convert Array to Object[][] error

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a simple script in google doc, but when I run it stops at line 15 with error as in the title. It works if only I remove that line. Can you help me please?

```js
function influencer_update() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Influencer'); 
  var dzis = sheet1.getRange('O1').getValue();  //today date
  var lista = sheet1.getRange('Q2:Q').getValues();  //list of values
  var lista_st = sheet1.getRange('D2:D').getValues(); //list of values to update
  var daty = sheet1.getRange('O2:O').getValues();  //list of dates, when value was last update
  for (i in lista) {
    if (lista[i]>0) {  
      lista_st[i]=lista[i]
      daty[i] = dzis
      
    }  
  }
  sheet1.getRange('D2:D').setValues(lista_st);
  sheet1.getRange('O2:O').setValues(daty);
  Browser.msgBox('daend');
}
```

Comment: Is `lista` an `Array`?

Comment: yes, only 'dzis' is not an array

Comment: `for...in` syntax is to be used on objects. `i` is the key, and `lista[i]` will get the value of the property on the lista object. Since lista is an Array, and not an object, you need to use an array iterator like `for`, `for...of`, `map`, `forEach`, etc.

Comment: What is `'dzis'`?

Comment: If you change `for(i in lista)` to `for (var i of lista)` your code should work..

Comment: Is `sheet1.getRange('O2:O').setValues(daty);` the line 15? can you do a `console.log(daty)` to see the value in daty?

Comment: I use for (i in lista) but then return to sheet another 2 arrays 'lista_st' and 'daty'. And 'lista_st' works fine, but 'daty' gets a mismatch error. Yes line 15 is  sheet1.getRange('O2:O').setValues(daty);

Comment: Just change `for (var i in lista)` to `for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++)` then

Answer (score 1):

I believe `setValues()` and `getValues()` always uses 2d array. When you do `daty[i] = dzis`, it converts `daty` to 1d array. Hence it gives you the error message `Can't convert Array to Object[][]`. If you change the line

`daty[i] = dzis`

to

`daty[i][0] = dzis`
or
`daty[i] = [dzis]`

should fix the problem.